# Multiple threads waiting on a lock held, in multiple thread dumps - deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading

We had a incident where our servers were slow, I have about 4 thread dumps about 3 seconds apart from that time.

While analyzing, I see one specific thread T is holding a Lock L, and 100+ threads are in contention for L, in each of the thread dumps. Also T is waiting is for lock LL which is not found to be held by any other thread in all of the thread dumps for those 12 secs. The incident was in the past so I cannot get more dumps.

This thread holds a lock which blocks many other threads:

> 10.61.33.43 [1480509049227] GET /xyz/asd/asd/asd.html HTTP/1.1" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa630050800 nid=0xf8fa waiting for    monitor entry
>   [0x00007fa62e281000]    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object
>   monitor)  at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentTracker.setSegment(SegmentTracker.java:152)
>     - locked <0x0000000601bd8b78> (a org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentTracker)

This message repeats many(100+) times in all the thread dumps

> waiting to lock <0x0000000601bd8b78> (a
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentTracker)

So my questions are:

1. Can we call this a deadlock (even though I can't find the circular lock chain) and assume that this is causing a slow down on the server?
2. Is it normal/usual for so many threads to wait on for a lock for this amount of duration? Can we conclude anything meaningful from this?

Update:

> "10.61.33.43 [1480509049227] GET /ads/asdf/asf/sdf.html HTTP/1.1" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa630050800 nid=0xf8fa waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fa62e281000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentTracker.setSegment(SegmentTracker.java:152)
>       - locked <0x0000000601bd8b78> (a org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentTracker)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentTracker.getSegment(SegmentTracker.java:137)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentId.getSegment(SegmentId.java:108)
>       - locked <0x000000066f619d50> (a org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentId)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.Record.getSegment(Record.java:82)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.MapRecord.getEntry(MapRecord.java:154)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.MapRecord.getEntry(MapRecord.java:186)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeState.getChildNode(SegmentNodeState.java:383)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.counter.jmx.NodeCounter.child(NodeCounter.java:56)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.counter.jmx.NodeCounter.getEstimatedNodeCount(NodeCounter.java:111)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.property.strategy.ContentMirrorStoreStrategy.count(ContentMirrorStoreStrategy.java:291)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.property.strategy.ContentMirrorStoreStrategy.count(ContentMirrorStoreStrategy.java:178)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.property.PropertyIndexLookup.getCost(PropertyIndexLookup.java:131)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.nodetype.NodeTypeIndexLookup.getCost(NodeTypeIndexLookup.java:70)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.nodetype.NodeTypeIndex.getCost(NodeTypeIndex.java:56)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.QueryImpl.getBestSelectorExecutionPlan(QueryImpl.java:866)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.QueryImpl.getBestSelectorExecutionPlan(QueryImpl.java:795)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.ast.SelectorImpl.prepare(SelectorImpl.java:284)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.QueryImpl.prepare(QueryImpl.java:570)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.QueryEngineImpl.executeQuery(QueryEngineImpl.java:183)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.query.QueryManagerImpl.executeQuery(QueryManagerImpl.java:132)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.query.QueryImpl$2.perform(QueryImpl.java:104)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.query.QueryImpl$2.perform(QueryImpl.java:100)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.perform(SessionDelegate.java:202)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.query.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:99)
>       at com.day.cq.search.impl.builder.QueryImpl.executeXpath(QueryImpl.java:391)
>       at com.day.cq.search.impl.builder.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:429)
>       at com.day.cq.search.impl.builder.QueryImpl.getResult(QueryImpl.java:106)
>       at com.cat.wcm.core.helper.JCRHelper.queryJCR(JCRHelper.java:107)
>       at com.cat.wcm.core.helper.JCRHelper.queryJCR(JCRHelper.java:80)
>       at com.cat.wcm.core.helper.ProductCompatibilityMatrixHelper.getTableRowDataValue(ProductCompatibilityMatrixHelper.java:292)
>       at com.cat.wcm.core.helper.ProductCompatibilityMatrixHelper.modelRowDataValue(ProductCompatibilityMatrixHelper.java:238)
>       at org.apache.jsp.apps.catDotCom.components.productCompatibilityTable.productCompatibilityTable_jsp._jspService(productCompatibilityTable_jsp.java:221)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:547)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
>       at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:133)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:259)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:117)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:322)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:216)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:103)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter$ForwardRequestDispatcher.include(WCMComponentFilter.java:445)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.includeResource(IncludeTag.java:224)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:91)
>       at org.apache.jsp.apps.catDotCom.components.pages.productFamilyPage.content_jsp._jspx_meth_cq_005finclude_005f9(content_jsp.java:724)
>       at org.apache.jsp.apps.catDotCom.components.pages.productFamilyPage.content_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f4(content_jsp.java:695)
>       at org.apache.jsp.apps.catDotCom.components.pages.productFamilyPage.content_jsp._jspService(content_jsp.java:277)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.includeScript(IncludeTag.java:167)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:87)
>       at org.apache.jsp.apps.catDotCom.components.pages.productFamilyPage.body_jsp._jspx_meth_cq_005finclude_005f2(body_jsp.java:241)
>       at org.apache.jsp.apps.catDotCom.components.pages.productFamilyPage.body_jsp._jspService(body_jsp.java:171)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.includeScript(IncludeTag.java:167)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:87)
>       at org.apache.jsp.apps.catDotCom.components.pages.page.page_jsp._jspx_meth_cq_005finclude_005f1(page_jsp.java:282)
>       at org.apache.jsp.apps.catDotCom.components.pages.page.page_jsp._jspService(page_jsp.java:237)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:547)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
>       at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:133)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:259)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:117)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:322)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:216)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:103)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter$ForwardRequestDispatcher.include(WCMComponentFilter.java:445)
>       at org.apache.jsp.libs.foundation.components.primary.cq.Page.Page_jsp._jspService(Page_jsp.java:106)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
>       at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:547)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
>       at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:133)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:371)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:171)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
>       at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:81)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler.doFilter(ActivityRecordHandler.java:155)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73)
>       at com.adobe.cq.dam.s7imaging.impl.auth.MemoryTokenAuthHandler.doFilter(MemoryTokenAuthHandler.java:156)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:201)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(ContentDispositionFilter.java:152)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:292)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:243)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.cognifide.slice.core.internal.filter.ContextRequstFilter.doFilter(ContextRequstFilter.java:84)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.analytics.provisioning.impl.UserAuthenticationRequestFilter.doFilter(UserAuthenticationRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:95)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:269)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.doFilter(CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.java:88)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:77)
>       at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:56)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:120)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:137)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:217)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:336)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:297)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>       at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>       at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>       at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>       at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>       at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: Jackrabbit version... 1.2.3? Please provide more of the thread's stacktrace. It could be an issue in this version of Jackrabbit. If you upgrade to 1.3.3, the code is completely different.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - 1.2.7. PFA the full stack trace for that thread.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting thing about this situation is why your first thread is waiting for monitor [0x00007fa62e281000]. This monitor should be owned by another thread. You should be able to see this from the thread dump. This is not necessary a dead lock. The monitor can just be owned by a thread performing some long running task (like calculating PI). This would effectively starve other threads while not being a dead lock.
To avoid this you should find out why this monitor is not available for a long time and rethink your locking strategy.

Answer (score 0):

(Nothing in this answer is specific to Jackrabbit)

Strictly, deadlock means there's some form of mutual waiting -- A is waiting for B, B is waiting for A, therefore both will wait forever.

So unless you know what's stopping `T` from releasing its lock, you can't formally say that it's deadlock. All you can say is that `T` held the lock for some amount of time (or possibly didn't release it until the system was forced to stop).

If threads are blocking for a significant amount of time, then obviously clients of those threads are going to notice slowness.

In addition, it's likely that each thread is associated with some heap, so you might be consuming more memory than necessary, leading to swapping and slowness.

The threads might be from a pool. If most of those threads are blocked, there will be fewer actively working threads, and clients may find themselves waiting for a thread to become available from the pool.

So, nothing very solid -- you need to find out what was causing T not to release the lock.